# PHP mail variable in header From:

Tags: php, email, variables, header

I have the following php script:

```
$odesilatel = $_SESSION['odesilatel']; //this works, $odesilatel displays the right content
$komu = "my@emailadress.cz, mysecond@emailadress.cz";
$predmet = "Objednávka z newsletteru";

$hlavicka = 'From: '.$odesilatel. "\n";
$hlavicka .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
$hlavicka .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\n"; 
$hlavicka .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\n";

$zprava = "I have some HTML code here. It's not important what it is...";

if(@mail($komu, $predmet, $zprava, $hlavicka)){
   echo 'E-mail byl úspěšně odeslán. Děkujeme za objednávku.';}
else{
  echo 'E-mail se bohužel nepodařilo odeslat.';}
```

If I delete the variable from the part of header where From: is and write here some email adress the mail is delivered. But if I use the variable, the mail is sent (echo is displayed), but it is not delivered. How to write correctly the header with From: and the variable?

Thank you very much for your help.

Bc. Michal Vlasák

Comment: Try "From: $odesilatel\n";

Comment: First of all get rid of "@" symbol before function call. This symbol silences all the errors if any.

Comment: `echo` or log somewhere your headers `$hlavicka` when using `$odesilatel`, perhaps that variable doesn't contain what you are expecting it to contain (maybe extra whitespace or newlines?)

Comment: @Fanis I tried this. I see From: nekdo@odnekud.cz MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit on the screen and
From: nekdo@odnekud.cz
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
in the source code. So I think there is no mistake here. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Just my few cents, but you should really code in English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it worked with what I have for code below, adding `session_start();` as well as my own Email address.

What I think may be happening is that, and since the `From` Email address is coming from a session name, and `session_start();` may not be included in your code, and it was not shown in yours, the Email `From` is empty and has not been set.

*(I would need to see your full code for both your HTML form and PHP.)*

Successful (tested) code:

```
<?php
session_unset(); // unset any previously set session and start a new one after
session_start(); // required when using sessions
// session variable set to Email (From) address
// Which could be coming from a POST variable
// $_SESSION['odesilatel'] = $_POST['from_email']; // example
$_SESSION['odesilatel'] = "email@example.com";

// check if session is empty
if(empty($_SESSION['odesilatel'])){ die("Session name is not set, stopping execution of script."); }

$odesilatel = $_SESSION['odesilatel']; //this works, $odesilatel displays the right content
$komu = "my@emailadress.cz, mysecond@emailadress.cz";
$predmet = "Objednávka z newsletteru";
$hlavicka = 'From: '.$odesilatel. "\n";
$hlavicka .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
$hlavicka .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\n"; 
$hlavicka .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\n";
$zprava = "I have some HTML code here. It's not important what it is...";

if(mail($komu, $predmet, $zprava, $hlavicka)){
   echo 'E-mail byl úspešne odeslán. Dekujeme za objednávku.';

echo $_SESSION['odesilatel']; // echo'ed my Email address
}
else{ echo 'E-mail se bohužel nepodarilo odeslat.';}
```

What I suggest you do is to set a conditional statement to check whether or not the session name is set or not, or better yet to check if it is empty.

I.e.:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['odesilatel'])){ die("Session name is not set, stopping execution of script."); }
```

but if session is empty, for example `$_SESSION['odesilatel'] = "";` mail will still be sent, but will end up in SPAM since the `From` is not being recognized.

Therefore using `if(empty` would be a better option.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['odesilatel'])){ die("Session name is not set, stopping execution of script."); }
```

I also suggest you do a `var_dump();`

I.e.:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['odesilatel']);
```

or:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

to see what comes up, and if it is empty, then that would signal a problem as well as show you if the `From` is in fact set or empty.

Comment: I tried your suggestions on my new form and suddeny it's succesfull. So your suggestion is a solution I think. Thank you.

Comment: You're quite welcome, glad I could help to offer a solution. @MichalVlasák

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the MIME-Version and Content-type first.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; //or another encoding
$headers .= 'From: ' . $variable .  "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not solution. The header is suddenly the part of the message and I got the spam warning message additionaly.

Answer (score 0):

And finally email.php that send the data by the e-mail. There are used your suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <META name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <TITLE>Potvrzení údajů</TITLE>
  <STYLE type="text/css">
    .tabulkaobjednavka{border: 1px solid #339935;}
    .tabulkanadpis{font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #339935; padding-left: 5px;}
    .bunkyobjednavky{font-family: serif; font-size: 14px; color: #339935; padding-left: 5px;}
  </STYLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['potvrdit'])){
      $vypis = $_SESSION['vypis'];
      $odesilatel = $_SESSION['odesilatel'];
     if(empty($_SESSION['odesilatel'])){ die("Session name is not set, stopping execution of script.");}

      $komu = "michal.vlasak@1sdzp.cz";
      $predmet = "Objednávka z newsletteru";
      $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n"; 
      $headers .= 'From: ' . $odesilatel;
      $zprava = 
      "
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
      <HTML>
        <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
        <STYLE type=\"text/css\">
          td.tabulkaobjednavka{border: 1px solid #339935;}
          td.tabulkanadpis{font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #339935; padding-left: 5px;}
          td.bunkyobjednavky{font-family: serif; font-size: 14px; color: #339935; padding-left: 5px;}
        </STYLE>
        <TITLE>E-mail</TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>".$vypis."</BODY>
      </HTML>";

      if(mail($komu, $predmet, $zprava, $headers)){
            echo '<P class="bunkyobjednavky">E-mail byl úspěšně odeslán. Děkujeme za objednávku.</P>';}
      else{
            echo '<P class="bunkyobjednavky">E-mail se bohužel nepodařilo odeslat.</P>';}}
  ?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I don't know what to do. I think about it over the month.